# Как сделать, чтобы изображение подстраивалось под размер экрана

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, transform, scale

Я хочу, чтобы изображение на моем экране подстраивалось под размер экрана.

Помогите, пожалуйста, кому не сложно.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))
pygame.display.set_caption('OnePiece')
Icon = pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(Icon)
Map = pygame.image.load("Baratie.png")
Luffy = pygame.image.load('Luffy.png')
x = 10
y = 885
speed = 5
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
done = True
while done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = False``
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_a] and x - 5:
        x -= speed``
    if key[pygame.K_d] and x < 1000 - 50 -5:
        x += speed
    screen.blit(Map, (0,0))


screen.blit(Luffy, (x, y))
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я отметил для вас строки, на которые надо обратить внимание.

Также попробуйте нажимать клавиши со стрелками.

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600

boyut = (width, height)
pencere = pygame.display.set_mode(boyut)

background = pygame.image.load("lena.jpg")                          # !!! 
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (boyut))            # !!! 

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Parca(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x = width /2,y = height / 2):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png").convert()
        
        self.image.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x,y)

    def update(self, *args):
        up,down,right,left = args

        if self.rect.x > width:
            self.rect.x = 0
        if self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = width
        if self.rect.y > height:
            self.rect.y = 0
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.rect.y = height

        if right:
            self.rect.x += 10
        if left:
            self.rect.x -= 10
        if up:
            self.rect.y -= 10
        if down:
            self.rect.y += 10


parca1 = Parca()
all_sprites.add(parca1)

while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:sys.exit()

    if keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        up,down,right,left = keys[pygame.K_UP],keys[pygame.K_DOWN],keys[pygame.K_RIGHT],keys[pygame.K_LEFT]
        all_sprites.update(up,down,right,left)

    pencere.blit(background,(0,0))                                      # !!!
    all_sprites.draw(pencere)                                           # !!!
    pygame.display.update()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**lena.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**ball.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Comment: Ненужные круглые скобки в `background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (boyut))` :)

Comment: Спасибо большое